# need help to use jQuery effect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I am using this function to make animation for boxes

```
$('.row3').adipoli({
                    'startEffect' : 'transparent',
                'hoverEffect' : 'boxRandom'
                });
```

there is an other effect what i want to use

```
$('.row1').adipoli({
                    'startEffect' : 'normal',
                    'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
                });
```

I just want to use both effect for one box so is it possible to use? if yes, how can i use?

i tried this one but it is not working

```
$('.row3').adipoli({
                    'startEffect' : 'transparent',
                'hoverEffect' : 'boxRandom',
                    'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
                });
```

Comment: how about creating a JSFiddle.

Comment: How can you use two `'hoverEffect'` properties for the same element?

Comment: I don't think, that you can use two hover effects for same element. It's not logical

Comment: we cannot assign two properties to same element

Comment: I  am using this jQuery 
http://cube3x.com/demo/adipoli-jquery-image-hover-plugin/

Comment: this is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.io

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [code of the plugin](http://cube3x.com/demo/adipoli-jquery-image-hover-plugin/js/jquery.adipoli.js), it is not possible to have multiple hover effects applied.

If you require this functionality you would be best to contact the author of the plugin to see if he can change this behaviour, or try and do it yourself or you could use another plugin which does have allow this behaviour.